# как с помощью унарного плюса преобразовать полученное значение из promt в число в JS

Tags: javascript, alert

> Напишите программу, которая работала бы следующим образом: в prompt вводится значение. С помощью унарного плюса (арифметический оператор) необходимо преобразовать его в число, затем проверить с помощью typeof, принадлежит ли оно к множеству Number.
>
> Если это число, то вывести в консоль чётное оно или нечётное.

Вопрос вот в чем когда мы вводим числа и буквы программа работает но когда вводим строку типа "2" преобразования из строки в число не происходит, получаем "Ошибка, введено НЕ ЧИСЛО". Вопрос - как с помощью унарного плюса преобразовать полученное значение из promt в число?

```
const result = +prompt('Введите четное число', '')
if (typeof +result !== 'number') {
  alert('Упс, кажется, вы ошиблись')
} else if (isNaN(result % 2)) {
  alert('Ошибка, введено НЕ ЧИСЛО')
} else if (result % 2 === 0) {
  alert('Число четное')
} else {
  alert('число нечетное')
}
```

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса.... в чём проблема? сейчас ты делаешь то что и хотел. не?

Comment: Вероятно в первом условии надо сравнивать не с 'number', а с Number. Ты сравниваешь тип со строкой, а надо тип с типом.

Comment: @DenisIgorevich почему?  `typeof 666`  будет `'number'`, а не Number

Comment: Да вроде всё работает. Или вы прямо `"2"` с кавычками вводите? Не, так не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вводя в prompt: 2,в переменную result вернётся строка "2", а если вводить в prompt: "2", то вернётся строка ""2"", по этому с помощью унарного плюса преобразовать полученное значение не получиться. Вернется NaN.